# After installation of Sublime 4 wrong order of search in files results - reverse instead of ABC, how to solve?

Tags: search, sublimetext4

After installation of Sublime 4 it shows the search results (multiple files search) in reverse order instead of ABC.

Can't find any solution in Google. Even tried to change settings manually `Preference -> Key bindings`:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find", "reverse": false} },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "find_in_files", "reverse": false} }
]
```

but without result:

```
Searching 729 files for "veh.category"

/home/me/Projects/mycompany/myproject/app/views/veh/_fm_form.html.haml:

/home/me/Projects/mycompany/myproject/app/views/veh/_form.html.haml:

/home/me/Projects/mycompany/myproject/app/views/veh/_veh.html.haml:

/home/me/Projects/mycompany/myproject/app/views/events/_veh.html.haml:

7 matches across 5 files
```

Link to Sublime Forum on [forum.sublimetext.com](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/after-installation-of-sublime-4-wrong-order-of-search-in-files-results-reverse-instead-of-abc-how-to-solve/59391)

Link to Git Sublime Issues Forum on https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/4700

P.S.

Ubuntu 20.04

Sublime 4107

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem. I thought the order is reversed, but now I think it is even unordered. Maybe it is sorted now by last modified date?

I would be interested in a solution, too.

A workaround is as follows:

- use version 3 and version 4 parallel:

  - see https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/side_by_side.html
  - downloaded Sublime Text 3 and put in application folder
    https://www.sublimetext.com/3
  - renamed `Sublime Text.app` to `Sublime Text 3.app`
  - created `/Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 4`
  - renamed `/Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text` to : `/Users/thomasglaser/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3`
- when starting Sublime Text 3 there was an error popup `Error loading syntax file "Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax": Unable to read Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax`

  - see https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/error-loading-syntax-file-json-error/25611/6
  - closed all open workspaces and projects thus tabs or windows
  - because of that there was the line

    `“syntax”: “Packages/JSON/JSON.sublime-syntax”`

    in file

    `/Users/<Username>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session`
  - after restarting sublime Text 3 no error popup came again
- get rid of 'Update Availabel' Popup

  - see https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-do-i-disable-update-checks/43492/7
  - add line `{"update_check": false,}` to `Preferences.sublime-settings`
  - maybe this works only for licensed accounts